# Indexing a Sharepoint list column which contains blank values

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a largish Sharepoint list, (10,000s of items), which has an index on a column which I need for fast retreival of items which have a value < 100 in this column. This will be about 0.5% of the items. However, about 95% of the items will have a blank value in this column. (The remaining items will have a value between 0 and 99).

Will indexing all these blank values cause performance issues?

The list is used within a Microsoft PowerApp.

So far things are working ok but the data is going to triple in size soon and I don't want things to grind to a halt.